# How to calculate the mean of some elements from a vector in R?

Tags: r

X<-c(-95, 67, -92, 65, 20, 25, -28, 55, 53, -77)

That is my vector, I would like to get the mean of the positive numbers, and then get the mean if the negative numbers.

How could I do this? I have looked everywhere and nothing pops up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "which" as it will not consider any NA values

Mean of positive numbers:

```
mean(X[which(X>=0)])
[1] 47.5
```

Mean of negative numbers:

```
mean(X[which(X<0)])
[1] -73
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Mean of positive numbers
mean(X[X > 0])
# Mean of negative numbers
mean(X[X < 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tapply` :

```
tapply(X, X > 0, mean)

#FALSE  TRUE 
#-73.0  47.5
```

If you want to give good label names to the values.

```
tapply(X, ifelse(X > 0, 'positive', 'negative'), mean)

#negative positive 
#   -73.0     47.5
```